# Oracle JDBC connection with Weblogic 10 datasource mapping, giving problem java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

Tags: oracle, exception, weblogic, datasource, weblogic-10.x

Oracle JDBC connection with Weblogic 10 datasource mapping, giving problem java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

I am using weblogic 10 JNDI datasource to create JDBC connections, below is my config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:sec="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/security" xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/920 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/920.xsd">
  <name>XL-Reference-DS</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:oci:@abc.XL.COM</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>DEV_260908</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>password</name>
        <value>password</value>
      </property> 
      <property>
        <name>dll</name>
        <value>ocijdbc10</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>protocol</name>
        <value>oci</value>
      </property> 
      <property>
        <name>oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>baseDriverClass</name>
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
  <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <initial-capacity>1</initial-capacity>
    <max-capacity>100</max-capacity>
    <capacity-increment>1</capacity-increment>
    <test-connections-on-reserve>true</test-connections-on-reserve>
    <test-table-name>SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</test-table-name>
  </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
  <jdbc-data-source-params>
    <jndi-name>ReferenceData</jndi-name>
    <global-transactions-protocol>OnePhaseCommit</global-transactions-protocol>
  </jdbc-data-source-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

When I run a bulk task where there are lots of connections made and closed, sometimes it gives connection closed exception for any of the task in the bulk task.

Below is detailed exception'

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:207)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.ensureOpen(OracleStatement.java:3512)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3265)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3367)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming some connections are working, it's probably not a config problem. Could be the code of your bulk task - is it not running through a single block of opening and closing connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to connection sharing across code....
bad programming.... :( corrected it....
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can change `<global-transactions-protocol>` parameter to `none` and execute the code:

```
<jdbc-data-source-params>
    <jndi-name>ReferenceData</jndi-name>
    <global-transactions-protocol>none</global-transactions-protocol>
</jdbc-data-source-params>
```